# How to get the resource id when adding a new event in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using multiple resource view.
Now when I create any event for any resource, how do I get the resource ID,Name in select function?

i'm trying to add a new event manually (selecting a time range) to a specific resource, so I need the resourceId after doing it to save the event on DB. The method select: function (start,end,allDay) only gives me the time range but not the resourceId if I'm working with multiple resources. Any solution?

I have tried:

`select: function(start, end, resourceId){alert(resourceId)}`, the alert is: **false**

`select: function(start, end, event){alert(event.resourceId)}`, the alert is: **undefined**

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what are your "multiple resources" ?

Comment: I have 3 resources named Resource1,Resource2,Resource3.The resources vertically and time horizontally.And i want to add events to a specific resource.I need the resourceId For each event after doing it to save the event on DB.

Comment: Plz show this link http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/         see the "Resource Day View".I want the same

Comment: Is event an array? You could try event[0].resourceId

Comment: @Monica: which plugin do you use ? plain [fullcalendar](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar) , or [ikelin's fork](https://github.com/ikelin/fullcalendar) ? Please edit your question to add this point.

Comment: getting the code from this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Ffullcalendar-asp-net%2Fdownloads%2Fdetail%3Fname%3DCalendarSitev1.1.zip%26can%3D2%26q&ei=dKYVU6_8AoKPrQeVhICADg&usg=AFQjCNFuVOYJKp-81IMiZfb6GBCFgyd7qQ&sig2=gZW1DaMuX8AFCUn2cgu0xw&bvm=bv.62286460,d.bmk

Answer (score 0):

The `fullcalendar` plugin is not aware of "multiple resources".
You will have to get the "resource" from some other parameter.

Here are two simple examples :

- You can add a set of radio buttons "Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource 3" somewhere near the calendar.
  You should have the user select a resource before clicking&dragging on the grid.
  In the `select` callback, you can then get the resource by reading the selected radio button.
- Once the user has selected a time range, you can open a dialog, which shows a form containing the selected time span and an extra `<select>...</select>` menu to let the user choose which resource should be selected.

Comment: i have already done in this way using a dropdown that lists the resources.i will select one resource and add event under that resource,the resourceid will be passed to the database correctly.But i don't want this way,because the resource name already shown horizontally in the header portion,so no use for the dropdownlist.i want to enter events under each resources and get the corresponding resourceid for each event.Any idea?